# How to add group of users to a project with api PUT request?

Tags: rest, gitlab-api

For me adding user `/api/v4/{projectId}/members/{memberId}?access_level={levelId}`
working just fine but i don't know how to add group of users?? If I PUT groupId instead of userId it doesn't work. Error 404